# Arrays ingresar elementos en una array ya definida

Tags: java

Hola foro :D tengo una duda: hay alguna manera de ingresar elementos en un cualquier posición de un array?

este código me permite duplicar las partes que quiero, pero quiero que el duplicado lo pueda poner en la parte que desee de el array de caracteres

```
    System.out.println("Ingrese los parámetros : ");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();
        String resultado="";
        char[] aCaracteres = adn.toCharArray();
        for (i = 0; i < aCaracteres.length; i++)
            System.out.print(aCaracteres[i]);
        for (; a < aCaracteres.length && a <= b; a++) {
            System.out.print(aCaracteres[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Teren. ¿Puedes poner el codigo que has intentado , asi podremos ayudarte mejor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjunto mi codigo:

```
   // Datos de ejemplo
   String ejemplo ="perro";
   String palabra="gato";
   int posicion=3;
    // Vamos a insertar "gato" apartir de la 3 letra de perro
   String resultado="";
   char[] array = ejemplo.toCharArray();
    for (int i =0;i<array.length;i++){
        resultado += array[i];
        // Filtro por las posicion que me mandan
        if (i==posicion){
            for (int j =0;j<palabra.length();j++){
                resultado += palabra.charAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(resultado);
```

Comment: man sos un grande